# simple string concatenation in python for wrapping shell scripts

Tags: python, string, shell

I am trying to write a simple python script that wraps a shell command and prints it in a file. first_interface and second_interface are global variables that can have values like eth0 and eth1.

```
def createSetup(first_interface,second_interface):
    with open("setup","w") as f:
        f.write("#!/usr/bin/env python" + createHeader() +
"\n\
\n\
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE\n\
\n\
proc = Popen([\"ifconfig\"," +first_interface+ ",\"192.168.100.1\"], stdout=PIPE)\n\
\n\
")
```

but what i get is

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["ifconfig",eth0,"192.168.100.1"], stdout=PIPE)
```

My expected output is

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["ifconfig","eth0","192.168.100.1"], stdout=PIPE)
```

How can  I add the missing inverted commas before the global variable (eth0)?

Thanks, .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the double quote is missing, but the comma looks good.

```
proc = Popen([\"ifconfig\",\"" +first_interface+ "\",\"192.168.100.1\"], stdout=PIPE)\n\
```

should give you the expected output.

Note the escaped double quote (\") before and after the first_interface is added.